# .any? inside a case block not evaluating as expected

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I have the following situation:

```
type = "stringX"
someArray = ["stringX", "string1", "string2"]

case type
when "stringA"
  puts "a"
when "stringB"
  puts "b"
when someArray.any? { |x| x.include?(type) }
  puts "x"
when "stringC"
  puts "c"
end
```

What I was expecting to happen was that it would go through the `case` and once it evaluates the `.any?` method as true (because by itself it does evaluate to true), it would `puts` "x". However, that's not what's happening here, it just goes through the rest of the `case` and reaches a `raise` somewhere below that.

I'm wondering what's going on here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you expect the third `when` case to execute because its condition evaluates to true? Why not any of the other cases? Because by your own reasoning, *all* of them evaluate to true, since e.g. `"stringA"` evaluates to true (in fact, everything except `nil` and `false` evaluates to true).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Because I thought that, once it reached `when` it did something like check `"stringA" == "stringA"` and since that would evaluate to true, it would run the code for that `when`. By that analogy I tried the `.any?` case since by itself it evaluates to true. But yeah, not understanding what Ruby does in the `when` condition is the reason I was stuck

Comment: But by your *own* logic it would then check `true == "stringA"`, which is false. And that is actually pretty much exactly what happens, except the method is `===` not `==`.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know it checked `true ==(=) "stringA"`, I thought if the evaluation of the `when` condition _by itself_  was `true` it would run the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*` operator

```
value = "stringX"
some_array = ["stringX", "string1", "string2"]

case type
when "stringA"
  puts "a"
when "stringB"
  puts "b"
when *some_array # notice the * before the variable name!
  puts "x"
when "stringC"
  puts "c"
end
```

How does this work?

`when *some_array` checks whether `value` is an element in `some_array`

Comment: @SystemShock please be aware that this is NOT the same thing you tried to use though! ```someArray.any? { |x| x.include?(type) }``` will check if any of the strings in the array INCLUDE the type ("abcstringX" does include "stringX"), while ```when *some_array``` checks whether any of the strings in some_array are EQUAL to type ("abcstringX" is not equal to "stringX").

Comment: @Ninigi Ah, OK, thanks for the clarification. Thought it would working like that. But *some_array works for me here since it'll be checking exact strings against one another.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case one should use the brilliant answer by @akuhn

Whether you need to put *any random condition* inside the `case`, you can do it using `Proc#===`:

```
type = "stringX"
someArray = ["stringX", "string1", "string2"]

case type
when "stringA" then puts "a"
when "stringB" then puts "b"
#    ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE
when ->(type) { someArray.any? { |x| x.include?(type) } }
  puts "x"
when "stringC" then puts "c"
end
```

Comment: omg you are right! The question was about the strings in the array INCLUDING the type... I should learn to read questions xD

Comment: Oh and apparently answers too... You didn't see it either, but still provided the only real answer ^^

Comment: Think that'll be useful to me pretty soon. Thanks.

Comment: Using a block is a nice combo breaker!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I will not delete the answer, because I think there might be something in it you didn't know before, but it does not work for your usecase. For that you should look at mudasobwas answer

It does not quite work this way, because basically the case statement will compare the given object with the object(s) passed to `when`, about similar to this:

```
if type == "stringA"
  # ...
elsif type == "stringB"
  # ...
```

and so on, unless you use an empty case statement.

```
case
when type == "stringA"
# ...
```

This is similar to an if elsif statement though, so you don't really see that very often.
In your case however, we can make use of [Ruby's splat operator](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/)

```
case type
when "stringA"
  puts "a"
when "stringB"
  puts "b"
when *someArray
  puts "x"
when "stringC"
  puts "c"
```

Ruby's case statement can take multiple arguments with `when` which kind of works like an "or"

```
case "A"
when "B"
  puts "B"
when "C", "A"
  puts "C or A"
end
# => C or A
```

and the splat operator will fan out your array:

```
p ["a", "b"]
# => ["a", "b"]

p *["a", "b"]
# => "a"
# => "b"

p "a", "b"
# => "a"
# => "b"
```

Comment: Yeah, leave it, pretty useful. Thanks.